# Golang: How to handle and serve subdomains?

Tags: go

The problem is serving the domain as well as subdomains x,y,z (or in this example blog, admin, and design). When running the following and requesting blog.localhost:8080/ firefox cant find the server www.blog.localhost:8080.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var tpl *template.Template

const (
    domain = "localhost"
    blogDomain = "blog." + domain
    adminDomain = "admin." + domain
    designDomain = "design." + domain
)


func init() {
     tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
}

func main() {


    // Default Handlers
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)

    // Blog Handlers
    http.HandleFunc(blogDomain+"/", blogIndex)

    // Admin Handlers
    http.HandleFunc(adminDomain+"/", adminIndex)

    // Design Handlers
    http.HandleFunc(designDomain+"/", designIndex)

    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil) 

}

func index(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "index.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("template didn't execute: ", err)
    }
}

// Blog Handlers
func blogIndex(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "index.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("template didn't execute: ", err)
    }
}

// Admin Handlers
func adminIndex(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "index.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("template didn't execute: ", err)
    }
}

// Design Handlers
func designIndex(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "index.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("template didn't execute: ", err)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to serve subdomains using the standard library? If so how?

**EDIT:** Requesting localhost:8080/ works fine

**EDIT2:** I edited /etc/hosts to include the subdomains:

```
127.0.0.1 blog.localhost.com
127.0.0.1 admin.localhost.com
127.0.0.1 design.localhost.com
```

Pinging them works correctly but firefox cannot reach them.

Comment: "firefox cant find the server " --- is it in the DNS? What IP does it resolve to? What exactly "cant find" means?

Comment: How do you intend to resolve "www.blog.localhost"? Are you running  local DNS server, or have you entered all the possible subdomains in your hosts file?

Comment: @zerkms I am running on a local vm machine with firefox. 127.0.0.1:8080/ works. blog.127.0.0.1:8080 does not. Firefox gives no status code. The response is blank when I inspect the network.

Comment: @Conner: that's not how DNS works, you can't just prepend text to an IP address and have that resolve to something, `blog.127.0.0.1:8080` isn't a valid host. You also can't prepend subdomains to `localhost` without first defining them somewhere.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for the information! I updated the hosts to point to the local host but still run into the same issue. I am guessing that pointing them all to the same host does nothing though. I'll be working on it.

Comment: What "the same issue" is? You have not explained what "cannot reach them" is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the hosts file in your second edit, you can point firefox to, for example, `blog.localhost.com:8080` but then you also have to handle that domain pattern, i.e. `http.HandleFunc(blogDomain+":8080/", blogIndex)`.

If that's not what you want you can instead listen on port `80` i.e. `http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)`, you might need to run your app in sudo so that it has permission to use that port, then your `blog.localhost.com` should work.

Comment: I implemented your first solution and it works perfectly! I will have to read more into the ServeMux and Virtual Hosting. Thank you!